Google Map SDK(android): mapview oncreate() ANR
We are experiencing a lot of ANRs that are reported on both Play Console & Firebase Crashlytics. The stack trace on both, points to the same class of MapView in Google Maps. I am sharing the stack trace that we are getting in Firebase Crashlytics.
Devices: 75% Vivo 9% xiaomi 13% oppo 3%
OS: 58% android11 32% android12 10%
SDK Version:
play-services-maps 19.0.0
play-services-location 21.3.0
play-services-ads 23.3.0
(https://i.sstatic.net/cWAWBBug.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/D2hGfk4E.png)
How can this type of ANR be avoided
Code
/**
 * 
 */
 private fun setStampView(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    .......
    
    // Google Map View
    mMapView = findViewById(R.id.map_view)
    // Google Map Key
    val mapKey = BuildConfig.MAPS_API_KEY
    if(mapKey.isNotEmpty()){
        val mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState?.getBundle(mapKey)
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle)
    }
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this)
   // FusedLocationProviderClient
   mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
   // 
   mGeocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
 }

override fun setActityView(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
        super.setActityView(savedInstanceState)
    
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.activity_layout_main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            // v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, 0)
    
            mScreenTop = systemBars.top
            mScreenBottom = systemBars.bottom
    
            val displayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
            // val screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels
            mScreenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
            // 获取广告宽度
            mAdWidth = (mScreenWidth / displayMetrics.density).toInt()
    
            mBottomSystemBarsHeight = systemBars.bottom
            setBoottomSysToolViewHeight(mBottomSystemBarsHeight)
    
            insets
        }
    
        // 设置状态栏图标颜色为白色（亮色）
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView).apply {
            isAppearanceLightStatusBars = false // 设置为 false 使图标变为白色
        }
    
        ImageUtils.init(applicationContext)
    
        GPSMapCameraApp.gAppSharedPre?.let {
            // 保存主界面当前是否为激活的最高界面
            saveSPBoolean(it, SP_KEY_MAIN_IS_NOW_ACTIVATE, true)
        }
    
        // 埋点 
        logEvent(FireBaseEvent.ONE_PV, FireBaseEvent.PV_CAMERA_PAGE)
        // 埋点 
        logEvent(FireBaseEvent.TAKEPHOTO_PROCESS, FireBaseEvent.CAMERA_PAGE_SHOW)
    
        // 判断是否为新用户
        if (GPSMapCameraApp.gIsFirst) {
            // 埋点 
            logEvent(FireBaseEvent.NEW_USER_PROCESS, FireBaseEvent.NEW_USER_CAMERA_PAGE)
        }
    
        // 初始化声音播放
        initMediaPlayer()
    
        // 整个Activity区域
        mCLMain = findViewById(R.id.activity_layout_main)
    
        // 设置Google广告
        setGoogleAdView()
    
        // 设置相机预览全部区域
        setAllCameraPreview()
    
        mClTop = findViewById(R.id.main_cl_top_view)
    
        // 设置按钮
        m_imgTopSetting = findViewById(R.id.main_img_top_setting)
        // 设置按钮 外部区域
        mRlTopSetting = findViewById(R.id.main_rl_top_setting_external)
        mRlTopSetting.setOnClickListener {
            // 跳转到设置界面
            gotoSettingActivity()
        }
    
        // 闪光灯按钮
        mImgTopFlash = findViewById(R.id.main_img_top_flash)
        when (currentFlashMode) {
            ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_AUTO -> {
                mImgTopFlash.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_camera_flash_auto)
            }
    
            ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_OFF -> {
                mImgTopFlash.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_camera_flash_off)
            }
    
            ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON -> {
                mImgTopFlash.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_camera_flash_on)
            }
    
            else -> {
                mImgTopFlash.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_camera_flash_auto)
            }
        }
    
        // 闪光灯按钮触摸区域
        mRlTopFlash = findViewById(R.id.main_rl_top_flash_external)
        mRlTopFlash.setOnClickListener {
            // 显示闪光灯选择弹出对话框
            // showFlashPopupWindow(mImgTopFlash)
            if(::mllCameraFlashSet.isInitialized) {
                if(mBShowCameraFlashSet) {
                    mBShowCameraFlashSet = false
    
                    // 隐藏 Camera闪光灯设置相关界面
                    mllCameraFlashSet.visibility = View.GONE
                } else {
                    mBShowCameraFlashSet = true
    
                    // 显示 Camera闪光灯设置相关界面
                    mllCameraFlashSet.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    
        // 摄像头旋转按钮
        mImgTopRotate = findViewById(R.id.main_img_top_rotate)
        mRlTopRotate = findViewById(R.id.main_rl_top_flash_rotate)
        mRlTopRotate.setOnClickListener {
            // 摄像头旋转
            rotateCamera()
        }
    
        // 相机设置按钮
        mImgCameraSet = findViewById(R.id.main_img_top_camera_set)
        // mImgCameraSet.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_camera_set)
    
        // 相机设置按钮触摸区域
        mRlTopCameraSet = findViewById(R.id.main_rl_top_camera_set_external)
        mRlTopCameraSet.setOnClickListener {
            //
            if (::mRlCameraSet.isInitialized) {
                if (mBShowCameraSet) {
                    mBShowCameraSet = false
    
                    // 隐藏 Camera设置相关界面
                    mRlCameraSet.visibility = View.GONE
                } else {
                    mBShowCameraSet = true
    
                    // 显示 Camera设置相关界面
                    mRlCameraSet.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    
        // 聚焦Icon
        mImgCameraFocus = findViewById(R.id.main_img_camera_focus)
    
        // 覆盖在预览视图上的网格
        mGridOverlayView = findViewById(R.id.main_view_camera_grid)
        if (mBShowCameraSetGrid) {
            mGridOverlayView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            mGridOverlayView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    
        // 闪光界面
        mViewFalsh = findViewById(R.id.main_view_falsh)
    
        // 设置底部工具相关区域
        setBottomToosView()
    
        // 设置相机设置相关界面
        setCameraSetView()
    
        // 设置相机闪光灯模式设置相关界面
        setCameraFlashSetView()
    
        // 设置相机缩放信息界面
        setZoomInfoView()
    
        // 设置 stemp信息界面
        setStampView(savedInstanceState)
    
        //  设置横竖屏切换
        setOrientationChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
        mContext = this
    
        // 新建View之前初始化
        initBeforeCreateView()
    
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        // 设置
        setContentView(setActivityLayout())
    
        // 设置Actity View
        setActityView(savedInstanceState)
    
        // 新建View之后初始化
        initAfterCreateView()
    }

android "build.gradle.kts(Project)":
buildscript { 
    dependencies { 
        classpath("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1") 
    } 
}
    
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version "3.0.2" apply false
}

android "build.gradle.kts(Module: App)":
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
}

......

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.viewpager2)
    implementation(libs.androidx.recyclerview)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)

    // ViewModel
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.activity.ktx)

    // CameraX
    implementation(libs.camera.core)
    implementation(libs.camera.camera2)
    implementation(libs.camera.lifecycle)
    implementation(libs.camera.view)
    implementation(libs.camera.video)
    // CameraX KTX
    implementation(libs.camera.extensions)

    // Firebase
    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
    implementation(libs.firebase.analytics.ktx)
    implementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics.ktx)

    // Google
    // Maps SDK for Android
    implementation(libs.google.play.services.maps)
    implementation(libs.google.play.services.location)
    // google ads
    implementation(libs.play.services.ads)

    // 
    // implementation(libs.permissionx)

    // 
    implementation(libs.bumptech.glide)
    // 
    implementation(libs.chrisbanes.photoview)
    // Lottie 动画
    implementation(libs.lottie.compose)

    // exoplayer
    implementation(libs.google.android.exoplayer)

    // AgentWeb
    implementation(libs.agentweb.core)

    // 
    implementation(libs.getActivity.multiLanguages)

    // 
    implementation(libs.retrofit2.retrofit)
    implementation(libs.retrofit2.converter.gson)
    implementation(libs.okhttp3.okhttp)
    implementation(libs.okhttp3.logging.interceptor)

    //
    implementation(libs.me.samlss.broccoli)
}

"libs.version.toml "
[versions] 
    
........
    
#Firebase
firebaseBom = "33.1.2"
    
#Google 
# Maps SDK for Android
playServicesMaps = "19.0.0" 
playServicesLocation = "21.3.0" 
playServicesAds = "23.3.0"
    
......
    
[libraries] 

.........
    
#Firebase
firebase-bom = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebaseBom" } firebase-analytics-ktx = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx" } firebase-crashlytics-ktx = { module = "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx" }
    
#Google
#Maps SDK for Android
google-play-services-maps = { group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-maps", version.ref = "playServicesMaps" } 
google-play-services-location = { group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-location", version.ref = "playServicesLocation" } 
play-services-ads = { module = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads", version.ref = "playServicesAds"}

logs:
main (runnable):tid=1 systid=16033 
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.phoenix.am.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@243625205@243625202025.679729749.679729749:507)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cg.aG(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@243625205@243625202025.679729749.679729749:52)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ee.d(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@243625205@243625202025.679729749.679729749:24)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.r.bt(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@243625205@243625202025.679729749.679729749:158)
       at m.axu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@243625205@243625202025.679729749.679729749:21)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzc(zza.java:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzl.onCreate(zzl.java:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzah.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@19.0.0:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zac.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.4.0:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zaa.onDelegateCreated(zaa.java:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzai.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@19.0.0:5)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzai.createDelegate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@19.0.0:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.4.0:6)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(DeferredLifecycleHelper.java:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@19.0.0:4)
       at gpsmapcamera.timestampcamera.geotagphoto.gpscamera.module.main.MainActivity.setStampView(MainActivity.kt:3698)
       at gpsmapcamera.timestampcamera.geotagphoto.gpscamera.module.main.MainActivity.setActityView(MainActivity.kt:1693)
       at gpsmapcamera.timestampcamera.geotagphoto.gpscamera.common.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:40)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8119)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8103)

Most phones work fine。ANR often appears on vivo mobile phones, These vivo phones are not in china. How can this type of ANR be avoided
